# How to add an observer to NSNotificationCenter in a C++ class using Objective-C++?

Tags: iphone, objective-c++, nsnotificationcenter

I have a C++ class that I recently renamed from *.cpp to *.mm to support objective-c. So I can add the following objective-c code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(notificationHandler:) 
                                                 name:@"notify"
                                               object:nil];
```

- How do/Can I write the notificationHandler method in c++?
- Will setting addObserver:self property work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'd need an Objective-C class to handle Objective-C notifications. *Core Foundation to the rescue!*

In.. wherever you start listening for notifications, e.g. your constructor:

```
static void notificationHandler(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo);

MyClass::MyClass() : {
    // do other setup ...

    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver
    (
        CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter(),
        this,
        &notificationHandler,
        CFSTR("notify"),
        NULL,
        CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately
    );
}
```

When done, e.g. in your destructor:

```
MyClass::~MyClass() {
    CFNotificationCenterRemoveEveryObserver
    (
        CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter(),
        this
    );
}
```

And finally, a static function to handle the dispatch:

```
static void notificationHandler(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {
    (static_cast<MyClass *>(observer))->reallyHandleTheNotification();
}
```

Ta da!

Comment: Oh cool. I was wondering what this core foundation thing was about. thanks mate

Comment: impressive. would these CF* functions be considered "toll free bridge" to the "normal" NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: No, `CFNotificationCenter` is not toll-free bridged with `NSNotificationCenter`. So a custom instance of either will not be usable in the other API. However, if you use a standard center in either (e.g. `CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter()` or `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`) and post a notification to it, the notification is posted to both sets of listeners (i.e. the interfaces are distinct, but the underlying system is the same.)

Answer (score 18):

Or you could also just use blocks and do:

```
[
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName: @"notify"
    object: nil
    queue: nil
    usingBlock: ^ (NSNotification * note) {
        // do stuff here, like calling a C++ method
    }
];
```

Comment: This looks great.  How you do you remove it though?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1411723-addobserverforname?language=objc
Pretty clean way, have a look.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add a C++ method as an observer because of how Objective-C method handles method invocation vs C++. You must have an Objective-C class (Declared with `@interface Class` .. `@end`) to respond to those methods.

Your only option is to wrap your C++ class in an Objective-C class, or just have a very light wrapper that just has a reference to an object and calls a method statically once the notification arrives.

Comment: :( I was afraid the answer was going to be something like that. Thanks for the response