# objective-c++ and objective-c communication

Tags: ios

I use NSNotificationCenter and postNotification to notify the end of long time processing in objective-c code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  postNotificationName:@"done"  object:nil];//
```

I wonder if I can use the same mechanism when objective-c code(.m) inform objective-c++ code(.mm) the event of "done".

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this question will help you: [How to add an observer to NSNotificationCenter in a C++ class using Objective-C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062299/how-to-add-an-observer-to-nsnotificationcenter-in-a-c-class-using-objective-c)

The solution is using core foundation notification center, almost the same way as NSNotificationCenter in Foundation. Add observer in the beginning(constructor), remove observer in the end(destructor).